# NewtonSoft JsonConvert.DeserializeObject returns all properties as null

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I can't figure out what's wrong with this:

```
public class Product
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string tp { get; set; }
}

public class Return
{
    [JsonProperty("products")]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class BlingJson
{
    [JsonProperty("return")]
    public Return Return { get; set; }
}

public static void Run()
{
    string str = "{ \"return\": { \"products\": [ { \"product\": { \"code\": \"8147-048PA\", \"description\": \"LEGEND 220v - HAIR CUTTER\", \"tp\": \"P\" } }, { \"product\": { \"code\": \"08164-148PA\", \"description\": \"FINALE - HAIR CUTTER\", \"tp\": \"P\" } } ] } }";

    BlingJson json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlingJson>(str);
}
```

Upon deserialization, `json.Return.Products` is a list containing two Products, but all properties (`code`, `description` and `tp`) are null.

Formatted JSON for convenience:

```
{
    "return": {
        "products": [
            {
                "product": {
                    "code": "8147-048PA",
                    "description": "LEGEND 220v - HAIR CUTTER",
                    "tp": "P"
                }
            },
            {
                "product": {
                    "code": "08164-148PA",
                    "description": "FINALE - HAIR CUTTER",
                    "tp": "P"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've seen similar questions but didn't find one that applies to this case.
How to solve?

Thanks.

Comment: http://json2csharp.com/, or visual studio special past can show you the missing layer. between product and products.

Comment: @xdtTransform awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON implies you need a wrapper around the product object. For example:

```
public class ProductWrapper
{
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Which makes you `Return` class look like this:

```
public class Return
{
    [JsonProperty("products")]
    public List<ProductWrapper> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: David, hope you don't mind coming back to this, but I can't wrap my head (yeah, intended) around this. My understanding is that, in the JSON, `products` is a property of `return` and its type is an array of `product`. Am I getting it wrong? *(Let me know if you want me to incorporate this into my question, or even if I should ask a new one.)*

Comment: The question is asked and answered already, you can't change it now I'm afraid. Having said that, the problem is the json is unusual. The products array contains an array of objects (the wrapper) that contain product objects. If you can change the json, that would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a Wrapper class as mentioned by @DavidG to get it working per the given Json format. However, if you can't change your class, you have to tune your Json to this format:

```
{
    "return": {
        "products": [
            {
                "code": "A",
                "description": "B",
                "tp": "C"
            },
            {
                "code": "D",
                "description": "E",
                "tp": "F"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. In this case I can modify my classes while the json is returned by a service, but nevertheless this helped me comprehend the issue better. I had to copy it and apply the same indenting style as the original, though - perhaps consider updating your answer to account for the style, since it may help future readers ;) (I can also edit it myself if you'd like)

Comment: I've done the indentation, if you feel you can add more content, feel free to do so :)

Comment: Thanks, I modified it to match the original precisely (leaving out the property values anyway).